# Embed Array only counts one array (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that has a command that gives random Fandom links, and the user can specify the amount (under 10). When I try to do multiple embeds for my reply, it only registers one embed.

```
        var amount = Number(message.content.split(' ')[1]) || 1
        try {
          if (amount >= 10) {
            await message.reply({content: 'Amount too large! Setting amount to 3', ephemeral: true, allowedMentions: {repliedUser: false}})
           amount = 3 
          } else if (amount <= 0) {
            await message.reply({content: 'Amount cannot be 0 or lower! Setting amount to 3', ephemeral: true, allowedMentions: {repliedUser: false}})
            amount = 3
         }  
         const baseUrl = 'https://roblox.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Random'
         const embed_Array = []
         for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
             console.log(i)
             const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
              .setColor("Random")
              .setTitle("Random Fandom Page")
              .setDescription("Got **random Roblox fandom page!**")
              .setURL(baseUrl)
              .addFields(
                  {name: 'Random Link #' + i, value: baseUrl}
              )
            embed_Array.push(embed)
         }
         console.log("Finished", embed_Array)
         await message.reply({embeds: embed_Array, allowedMentions: {repliedUser: false}})
```

I tried to log the array, it shows up as multiple embeds, which is as expected. I tried to log the iterator number, logged as expected.